# Java Mail - Email Not Sending through Gmail

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to execute the following set of code but it's to no avail. I am using my Gmail account for this. I have 2-step verification disabled and I have allow less secured apps turned on yet I keep getting the error:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14

```
public void sendEmail()
{
    try
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()
        {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("example@gmail.com", "password");
            }
        });

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("example@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("example@company.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Testing Text");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Mail Sent!");

    } 

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read https://serverfault.com/questions/635139/how-to-fix-send-mail-authorization-failed-534-5-7-14 ?

Comment: Problem is not with the code. It works perfectly. There seems to an issue with the permissions.

Comment: What's the full message you get with the exception?  If necessary, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  If the message contains a URL to a google help page, did you read it and follow the instructions?

Comment: Sigh I found the problem. I needed to generate an app password after setting up 2-step verification. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks you guys so much for replying!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I needed to do was enable 2-step verification then generate an app password for the application. Thanks to everyone who responded. :)

Comment: could you explain how did you do that? I mean, enable the 2-step and generate an app pwd. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Aldeguer you have to head over to https://myaccount.google.com/security then down to "2-step verification". once you're there, enable it using a phone number. Once you've done that, "App Passwords" would appear under the 2-step verification link. Click that then you can create a password there.